# Upload File to firebase storage and get URL to save in a database in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I have react with redux app and `Asp.NetCorewebApi` as Back-end . I want to upload file to firebase storage and get its URL to save in a database table so that I can display it.
The file is uploaded successfully but it does not `setUrl` to save in state.
here is relevant part of `UploadMaterial.jsx` component when input file is selected.

```
             // component state variables
const[image,setImage]=useState(null);
    const[url,setUrl]=useState('');
    const[fileName,setFileName]=useState('');

         // handlechange function when file is selected
const handleChange = e => {
     const image = document.getElementById("uploadFile").files[0];
      setFileName(image.name); //set filename
     setImage(image);       // set file
 
     const uploadTask = storage.ref(`courseMaterial/${fileName}/`).put(image);
    
     uploadTask.on('state_changed',
         (snapshot) => {
             // progress function ....
             const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
             setProgress({ progress });
           
             
         },
         (error) => {
             console.log(error);
         },
        
     );
     () => {
            // complete function ....
            storage.ref(`courseMaterial`).child(`${fileName}`).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                setUrl(url);
                console.log(url); // why url is not updated?
            }) , (error) => {
                // error function ....
   
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    
 }
```

the file uploaded successfully but the URL is not updated so I am unable to save in state to send to my back-end database. Thanks in advance for help.
update:
here is the console.log and info screenshots.
[[image: screenshot infoscreenshot error]
here is the whole  component `UploadMaterial.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, withStyles, FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, Button, FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import {useForm} from "../../_helpers";
import {storage} from '../../firebase';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../../_actions/materialActions";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { Link,useParams,useHistory,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';

const styles = theme => ({
   
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 300,
    },
    smMargin: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
})

const initialFieldValues = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    postedBy: '',
    userName: '',
    courseId: '',
    courseTitle: '',
    type: '',
    fileTitle: ''



};

const UploadMaterial = ({ classes, ...props }) => {
    const[image,setImage]=useState(null);
    const[url,setUrl]=useState('');
    const[fileName,setFileName]=useState('');
    const[preview ,setPreview]=useState(null);
    const[progress,setProgress]=useState(0);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    //
    function useQuery() {
        return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
      }
      let query = useQuery();
       // let {fullName}=useParams();
       let courseId=query.get("courseId");
       let courseTitle=query.get("courseTitle");
    let history = useHistory()
      //
        
   const { addToast } = useToasts();
  //material-ui select
  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
     setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);
 //
 const user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))


 const handleChange = e => {
    
  
     const image = document.getElementById("uploadFile").files[0];
      setFileName(courseId+"-"+image.name);
     setImage(image);
     
     
    // setFileTitle(temp)
     
     setPreview(e.target.files[0])
     const uploadTask = storage.ref(`courseMaterial/${fileName}/`).put(image);
    
     uploadTask.on('state_changed',
         (snapshot) => {
             // progrss function ....
             const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
             setProgress({ progress });
           
             
         },
         (error) => {
             // error function ....
             addToast(" some error !check file size/type ", { appearance: 'error' })

             console.log(error);
         },
        
     );
     () => {
            // complete function ....
            storage.ref(`courseMaterial`).child(fileName).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                setUrl(url);
                
            }) , (error) => {
                // error function ....
   
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    
 }
 console.log("url:",url);
  console.log("fileName:",fileName);
 
  
 
    
    
    //validate()
    //validate({title:'jenny'})
    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        let temp = { ...errors }
        if ('title' in fieldValues)
        temp.title = fieldValues.title ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('type' in fieldValues)
        temp.type = fieldValues.type ? "" : "This field is required."
  
       
        if ('description' in fieldValues)
        temp.description = fieldValues.description ? "" : "This field is required."
  
             
         setErrors({
            ...temp
        })

        if (fieldValues == values)
            return Object.values(temp).every(x => x == "")
    }

    const {
        values,
        setValues,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        resetForm
    } = useForm(initialFieldValues, validate)

   ///
  useEffect(()=>{
    setValues( { ...values, postedBy:user.id,userName:user.username,
        courseId: courseId,courseTitle: courseTitle,
        fileTitle:url})
        
  
    },[values.title])
    
    // for tinymce editor
    console.log("values:",values);
    //console.log("url:", url);
    const onSuccess = () => {
        resetForm()
        addToast("uploaded successfully", { appearance: 'success' })

    }
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validate()) {
            
            addToast("working please wait !", { appearance: 'warning' })
            // file upload code here
           
            if(progress==100)
            dispatch(actions.create(values, onSuccess))


    }
   
    }
    console.log("progress:",progress);
 
    
    return (
        <form autoComplete="off"  noValidate className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           <hr/>
           
        <input id="uploadFile" type="file" className={classes.formControl} onChange={handleChange}/><br/>

        <br/><LinearProgress value={progress}  color="primary" max="100" /><br/>
         <TextField
            placeholder="Enter Title in short"
                        name="title"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="title"
                        value={values.title}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.title && { error: true, helperText: errors.title })}
                    />
                <br/>
                <FormControl variant="outlined"
                        className={classes.formControl}
                        {...(errors.type && { error: true })}
                    >
                        <InputLabel ref={inputLabel}>Material type</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            name="type"
                            value={values.type}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            labelWidth={labelWidth}
                        >
                            <MenuItem value="">Select type</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="helpingfile">Helping File</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="instructionfile">Instruction file</MenuItem>
                             
                           
                        </Select>
                        {errors.type && <FormHelperText>{errors.type}</FormHelperText>}
                    </FormControl><br/>
                                   
                    <TextField
            placeholder="Enter short description"
                        name="description"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Description"
                        value={values.description}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.description && { error: true, helperText: errors.description })}
                    /><br/>
                    
 
                    <div>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            type="submit"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                            onClick={resetForm}
                        >
                            Reset
                        </Button>
                        <Button   onClick={() => history.goBack()}
               size="small"  className={classes.smMargin} variant="contained" color="secondary">
                 back
               </Button>
                    </div>
               
            
        </form>
    );
}






export default (withStyles(styles)(UploadMaterial));
```

Comment: 1) When you run this code in a debugger, does it every reach the call to `getDownloadURL`? If so, does it ever reach the `console.log(url)` inside the callback? If so, what's the output you get? 2) Where are you saving the URL to the database?

Comment: Hi,@Frank it does not return the url in then part of request.however if the file is already present on firebase folder and we try to upload same file the url is updated correctly.i want to save the url in filetitle field of a form component.an error shown in console is that two simultanious request to the same source like that.however the upload part works correct the progress goes from 0 to 100 and file is uploaded to `courseMaterial` folder. the error is in `getdownloadurl()` part

Comment: What happens when you step through this code line by line in a debugger? Does it get to `console.log(url);`? If so, what does it print?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, it does not get to `console.log(url)` . I have updated the question please see . i am ready to share more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up the indentation of your code, you notice the following problems:

```js
uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    // progress function ....
    const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
    setProgress({ progress });
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  },
);        // PROBLEM: this bracket & semi-colon closes off on()
() => {   // <-- which means this function is floating and never actually called
  // complete function ....
  storage.ref(`courseMaterial`).child(`${fileName}`).getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => {
      setUrl(url);
      console.log(url); // why url is not updated?
    }),          // PROBLEM: this comma is outside of then()
  (error) => {   // <-- meaning this error function is also floating and never called
    // error function ....
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Fixing it, you get:

```js
uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    // file upload progress report
    const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
    setProgress({ progress });
  },
  (error) => {
    // file upload failed
    console.log(error);
  },
  () => {
    // file upload completed
    storage.ref(`courseMaterial`).child(`${fileName}`).getDownloadURL()
      .then(
        (url) => {
          // got download URL
          setUrl(url);
          console.log(url);
        },
        (error) => {
          // failed to get download URL
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
);
```

You can avoid this in the future using a `StorageObserver` instead of the three callback arguments to [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on).

This line:

```js
on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, nextCallback, errorCallback, completeCallback)
```

can be converted to:

```js
on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, {
  next: nextCallback, 
  error: errorCallback,
  complete: completeCallback
})
```

Which can be used like so:

```js
uploadTask.on('state_changed', {
  next(snapshot): {
    // file upload progress report
    const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
    setProgress({ progress });
  },
  error(error): {
    // file upload failed
    console.log(error);
  },
  complete(): {
    // file upload completed
    storage.ref(`courseMaterial`).child(`${fileName}`).getDownloadURL()
      .then(
        (url) => {
          // got download URL
          setUrl(url);
          console.log(url);
        },
        (error) => {
          // failed to get download URL
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
});
```

Comment: hi @samthecodingman ,thanks for help now the error is below: should I use the end `/` or `//` in upload?
    ` "code": 400,
    "message": "The path may not end with '/' or contain two consecutive '/'s"
  }`

Comment: hi @samthecodingman ,@stcm ,@Frank @FrankvanPuffelen the error is ` "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The path may not end with '/' or contain two consecutive '/'s"
  }`

Comment: @AhmedRanjha Looks like `fileName` is still `''` until after your function finishes. This causes your path to be `/courseMaterial//`. Try changing all instances of `${fileName}` with `${image.name}`. Also no need to tag spam we'll come back when we have some free time.

Comment: hi @samthecodingman thanks for help starting working after removing last `/` and changing filename as suggested by you. `     const uploadTask = storage.ref(`courseMaterial/${image.name}`).put(image);
` very thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you are useing useEffect hook as it is working asynchronous**
**Here is my code :**

```js
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = React.useState(null); // image selecting state
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(""); //url setting state
  
  const storage = getStorage();

  useEffect(() => {
    // declare the data getImage function
    const getImage = async () => {
      const ImageURL = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `${imageUpload.name}`));
      setImage(ImageURL);
    }
    // call the function
    getImage()
    console.log(image)
  }, [imageUpload])
  
  const uploadImage = () => {
    if (imageUpload == null) return;  
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `${imageUpload.name}`);
    uploadBytes(storageRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("Uploaded image");
    });
  };
```